# Installing latexdiff on a Mac

Tags: installing, latexdiff

I need to install latexdiff on my Mac, but have been unable to. The simplest approach `sudo port install latexdiff` gives me the error `sudo: port: command not found`.

Alternative installation instructions on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/) are unclear to me.

Can latexdiff be installed on a Mac from Terminal using the files available on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/)? If possible, how can this be done?

Comment: If you have MacTeX, you already have `latexdiff`

Comment: You can verify that it's installed by using `which latexdiff`.  If you have MacTeX installed this command should return `/usr/texbin/latexdiff`.

Comment: At least for me, it is located here based on the 2016 MacTex: `/opt/local/bin/latexdiff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here:

1. How to install latexdiff?
2. error `sudo: port: command not found`

You already got the answer for the first one from Egreg. MacTeX includes latexdiff Perl script. I just checked on my daughter's MacBook Pro. You probably want to replace default 2009 or something like that MacTeX version which came with OS X with the current. Do not use ports to install TeX on Mac!

Based upon the code you provided it looks like you do not have ports installed. I am an OpenBSD user so take my advices with a grain of salt but if I recall correctly you have to install firstly Xcode in order to bootstrap ports tool chain (gcc, binutils and usual stuff).

Comment: There is no version of MacTeX that comes with OS X. It is always installed separately, but you're right it shouldn't be installed with MacPorts (which it seems the OP doesn't have installed anyway.)

Comment: As Predrag said, you don't seem to have a working istallation of MacPorts. Try to install it with the help from here: http://www.macports.org/install.php

Answer (score 5):

Installing latexdiff on a Mac (without having MacTeX installed e.g. if you use an online LaTeX editor):

1. Install Homebrew, the missing package manager for Mac ->
   https://brew.sh/
2. Install perl -> `brew install perl` (N.B. this step might not be necessary)
3. Install latexdiff -> `brew install latexdiff`
4. Keep latexdiff up-to-date -> `brew upgrade latexdiff`
5. Uninstall latexdiff -> `brew uninstall latexdiff`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you need with it, you can also use `brew install mactex` (this is rather slow to download, but it has all the tools, stylesheets, etc. which you might need).